# Can not find div by class name via Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to access the "events"  inside the div with class name "rps-wrapper" within the url `http://gridworlds-multiplayer.org/` but when I use the function I get an error.

```
    <div class="rps-wrapper">
        <ul id="events"></ul>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="chat-wrapper">
                <form id="chat-form">
                    <input id="chat" autocomplete="off" title="chat"/>
                    <button id="say">Say</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="src/client.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('*the site is here*')
rps_wrapper = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rps-wrapper')
```

Should get the div with class name rps-wrapper, but outputs error `elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".rps-wrapper"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)`

Comment: Can you check if there any iframe?

Comment: Is it possible to share url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the *events* within the `<div>` with class name **rps-wrapper** as the desired element is within an `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either ofthe following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME,"frame")))
    rps_wrapper = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rps-wrapper>ul#events")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME,"frame")))
    rps_wrapper = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rps-wrapper']/ul[@id='events']")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Is there any reason I could not locate the rps_wrapper object using the function find_element_by_class_name()? I can confirm that the object was loaded on the page at time of execution of said function.

Comment: @LudwigVonChesterfield Of-coarse you can use _classname_ but definitely you would need _WebDriverWait_ to switch to the `<frame>` first then locate the element.

Comment: But I do not use a <frame> tag.

Comment: Unless you switch to the `<frame>` you won't be able to access the desired element.